# Alterar valor de um campo quando uma condição for verdadeira

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa noite pessoal,

Conseguem me ajudar?

Preciso criar uma view com os dados abaixo, no entanto preciso criar uma condição em que quando o valor de MC.SITUACAO for igual 'A', os campos MC.VALORPAGO e MC.SITUACAO devem vir em branco (mesmo que a consulta tenham valores.  Abaixo a consulta que estou realizando:

```
SELECT
       PA.EMPRESA,
       PA.CONTRATO,
       PA.PARCELA,
       PA.SITUACAO,
       PA.PMT,
       PA.IOF,
       PA.VCTO,
       PA.SALDO,
       MC.DATAFINANCEIRA,          
       MC.VALORPAGO,
       MC.SITUACAO


FROM PARCELAS PA
    LEFT JOIN MOVIMENTOSCONTABEIS MC ON PA.EMPRESA = MC.EMPRESA
                                    AND PA.AGENCIA = MC.AGENCIA
                                    AND PA.CONTRATO = MC.CONTRATO
                                    AND PA.PARCELA = MC.PARCELA
                                    AND PA.ULTIMASEQUENCIA = MC.SEQUENCIA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `CASE`, que tem o seguinte formato:

`CASE condicao THEN valor`, que no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
       PA.EMPRESA,
       PA.CONTRATO,
       PA.PARCELA,
       PA.SITUACAO,
       PA.PMT,
       PA.IOF,
       PA.VCTO,
       PA.SALDO,
       MC.DATAFINANCEIRA,          
       CASE UPPER(MC.SITUACAO)
          WHEN 'A' THEN ''
          ELSE MC.VALORPAGO
       END VALORPAGO,
       CASE UPPER(MC.SITUACAO)
          WHEN 'A' THEN ''
          ELSE MC.SITUACAO
       END SITUACAO
FROM PARCELAS PA
    LEFT JOIN MOVIMENTOSCONTABEIS MC ON PA.EMPRESA = MC.EMPRESA
                                    AND PA.AGENCIA = MC.AGENCIA
                                    AND PA.CONTRATO = MC.CONTRATO
                                    AND PA.PARCELA = MC.PARCELA
                                    AND PA.ULTIMASEQUENCIA = MC.SEQUENCIA
```

Também usei a função `UPPER` para converter para maiúscula e garantir que sempre um "A" a ser considerado.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente assim funcione

```
    Select *
    FROM(Select PA.EMPRESA,
           PA.CONTRATO,
           PA.PARCELA,
           PA.SITUACAO,
           PA.PMT,
           PA.IOF,
           PA.VCTO,
           PA.SALDO,
           MC.DATAFINANCEIRA,
    MIN(CASE WHEN MC.SITUACAO = 'a' THEN '' END) AS MC.SITUACAO,
    MIN(CASE WHEN MC.SITUACAO = 'a' THEN '' END) AS MC.VALORPAGO
FROM PARCELAS PA
    LEFT JOIN MOVIMENTOSCONTABEIS MC ON PA.EMPRESA = MC.EMPRESA
                                    AND PA.AGENCIA = MC.AGENCIA
                                    AND PA.CONTRATO = MC.CONTRATO
                                    AND PA.PARCELA = MC.PARCELA
                                    AND PA.ULTIMASEQUENCIA = MC.SEQUENCIA
)
```

Comment: pq esta usando a função `MIN` com o `CASE`? e onde está a condição para exibir o campo caso o valor não seja "A"?